# CCCallFunc and ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Heres my problem I am trying to create a callback function for a action sequence in cocos2d for iphone but I keep getting bad access errors.

Here I create my call back

```
id myCallFunc = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self.delegate selector:@selector(playerAttack:data:) data:(__bridge void *)([[PlayerAttackPacket alloc] initWithPlayer:@"" attackChoice: [NSNumber numberWithInt: item.tag]]) ]; // to call our method
```

And here is the function thats called back, and when casting data the compiler says bad access.

```
-(void) playerAttack:(id)sender data:(void *)data
{
    PlayerAttackPacket* packet = (__bridge PlayerAttackPacket*)data;
    BattleModel *model = [BattleModel sharedInstance];
    int choice = packet.attackChoice.intValue;
    NSString * players = packet.player;
}
```

Player packet:

```
@interface PlayerAttackPacket : NSObject {
    NSString * player;
    NSNumber * attackChoice;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * player;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * attackChoice;
-(id) initWithPlayer: (NSString*)_player attackChoice: (NSNumber*)choice;
@end

@implementation PlayerAttackPacket
@synthesize player,attackChoice;

-(id) initWithPlayer: (NSString*)_player attackChoice: (NSNumber*)choice
{
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
        self.player = _player;
        self.attackChoice = choice;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? =(. My feeling is it has something to do with ARC but I'm not sure.

Comment: Where do you get the bad access exception? Where do you run the CCCallFuncND?

Comment: bad access happens in playerAttack when accessing 'data' the first time (see above). CCCallFunND is in CCSequence and called at the end of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For readability, here's your call func method reformatted:

```
void* data = (__bridge void*)[[PlayerAttackPacket alloc] initWithPlayer:@"" 
                               attackChoice: [NSNumber numberWithInt: item.tag]];
id myCallFunc = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self.delegate 
           selector:@selector(playerAttack:data:) data:data ];
```

What you do is this:

- allocate new object
- bridge cast it to void*
- pass it into CCCallFuncND

What ARC sees/does is this:

- new object allocated
- new object bridge cast (ignore)
- object goes out of scope after call func
- release object

You do not keep a strong reference to the object, therefore it is released by the time the selector is executed. Please don't use Ben's advice, I know it works but it's also dangerous in that it will leak memory any time the call func action doesn't actually execute the selector, ie when stopping the action/sequence or when changing the scene while call func is still running, waiting to execute the selector.

You can solve this in two ways:

- keep a strong reference to the new object until the selector is executed, ie as instance variable of the class
- use CCCallBlock instead

By all means use a block! It avoids the memory management problem and you don't have to have a strong reference to the object either. In fact, you don't even have to pass it to the block! Here's how it works:

```
PlayerAttackPacket* packet = [[PlayerAttackPacket alloc] initWithPlayer:@"" 
                               attackChoice: [NSNumber numberWithInt: item.tag]];

id myCallBlock = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

    // no bridge casting required, packet variable is accessible within the block
    // no memory management needed, block copies packet and keeps it alive
    BattleModel *model = [BattleModel sharedInstance];
    int choice = packet.attackChoice.intValue;
    NSString * players = packet.player;
           }];
```

Now I'm sort of guessing here but it seems to me like you created the PlayerAttackPacket class solely to pass several parameters into the CCCallFuncND. You can skip that with blocks as well!

```
NSString* player = @"player1";

id myCallBlock = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

    // whatever variables you need from the surrounding scope, you can just use
    // them as if they were local variables in the block!
    int choice = item.tag;
    NSString * players = player;
           }];
```

Blocks are super-convenient, and work better with ARC. Use blocks! Repeat: [use blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html).

Comment: Thanks! You are right about the packet, its only there because I wanted to pass several parameters. But also figured I might need it for when I implement battles with Game Center (I haven't looked into it much though yet so maybe I don't). BTW I read your tutorials a lot. They are a great help.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell but I think you have to change (__bridge void *) to (_bridge_retained void*) in your CCCallFuncND declaration and inside playerAttack when you cast it back change the cast to (_bridge_transfer PlayerAttackPacket*).

An important note is that if your scene is ended before your playerAttack method is called, so during the CCSequence, the data packet will never be released and will therefore leak. Also if the action is stopped there will be a leak as LearnCocos2D has pointed out.

I recommend you check out the CCCallBlock actions as they are much easier to use and you should not have this problem.

Comment: no no no no no! Don't use __bridge_retained there. If you were to stop the action, it would leak memory because then you can't match it with a __bridge_transfer. __bridge_retained is not to be used anywhere but Core Foundation classes, or anywhere where you have full control over the lifetime of the transferred object.

Comment: You are correct. This is a major flaw, I alluded to this in my answer but not well enough. Is there anyway to retain the object otherwise though or will the code need to be completely changed to not use CCCallFuncND?

Comment: You will have to keep a strong reference to the object until the selector is called. Instance variable works fine, then nil it in the selector. It's still a crudge compared to using blocks though. I sort of wish cocos2d 2.0 had done the right thing and removed the entire CCCallFunc actions in favor of their block counterparts.